# Pagination and displaying records in rows with Django templates

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pagination, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to get some pagination of GAE for python, but I cannot even get the tutorial (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/) working. I'm seeing conflicting responses here about where to go. Here is the code I'm using:

```
class EditCompanyHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):

    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/

    def get(self):
        company_list = Company.all()    
        paginator = Paginator(company_list, 25) 




You are using the default Django version (0.96). The default Django version will change in an App Engine release in the near future. Please call use_library() to explicitly select a Django version. For more information see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries#Django

E 2012-05-25 06:31:36.341

<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: cannot import name Paginator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~XX/1.359153909296057586/showcompanies.py", line 24, in <module>
    from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

I 2012-05-25 06:31:36.343

This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
```

I'm looking for a straightforward way to paginate.

If I update the djnago version to 1.1, I get the following:

```
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: cannot import name Paginator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~biomapit/1.359154059826228765/showcompanies.py", line 25, in <module>
    from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
```

Comment: that `def get(self)...` is all the code you're using? No imports?

Comment: Try extending the `EditCompanyHandler` class with Paginator too, like this `class EditCompanyHandler(webapp.RequestHandler, Paginator):`

Answer (score 0):

I know that , you should use django > 0.96 version if you want to import paginator.
And you add "from django.core.paginator import Paginator"  this module in showcompanies.py at the top. 
I think that you can define the wrong code section this (from django.core.paginator import Paginator) module
I used django 1.2 version and paginator was running in my project.